Is it possible to use a fallback ref if a branch doesn't exist for repository resources in Azure pipelines?
The pipeline seem to work fine as of now. It's dynamic in the sense that it will trigger for all release branches, for all repos, which is what we want.
What we would really want is the ability to use a fallback ref in case the branch that triggers the build, Build.SourceBranch, is not available for one or more of the repos.
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: <POOL_NAME>
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals  <AGENT_NAME>
# Overrides the value for Build.BuildNumber, which is used to name the artifact (ZIP file) that is produced

name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd)T$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: REPO-A
    type: git
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
    name: <COMPANY>/REPO-A
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - 'release/*'

  - repository: REPO-B
    type: git
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
    name: <COMPANY>/REPO-B
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - 'release/*'
          
stages:
- stage: 'BuildAndUploadArtifact'
  jobs:
  - job:
    workspace:
      clean: all
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: REPO-A
    - checkout: REPO-B

    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "hello, world!"

Consider these two scenarios:
Scenario 1 - works with this pipeline

REPO-A and REPO-B both have a release/2024-1 branch and a
release/2024-2 branch. A commit is made in the release/2024-1 branch
in REPO-A. Both repos are checked out with the release/2024-1 branch.

Scenario 2 - does not work with this pipeline

REPO-A have a release/2024-1 branch. REPO-B only has a MASTER branch.
A commit is made in the release/2024-1 branch in REPO-A. REPO-A is
checked out with the release/2024-1 branch, but REPO-B doesn't have
that branch. Result: The pipeline won't run.

We want to be able to specify a fallback ref for REPO-B, so that it could have fallen back on that branch. If that fallback ref would be specified with MASTER, then REPO-A would use the release/2024-1 branch and REPO-B would use the MASTER branch.
Is this possible to achieve today?
NOTE!: This pipeline is heavily simplified. In reality there are many more repos, and the repos are built together as one application in a later step.

Yes, you can dynamically define the variable value based on the source branch, and then use the variable for the repo-B ref value. so that it could have fallen back on repo-B to checkout.
Sample yaml below, in the if expression, add all condition when release/branch exists on both source repo.
trigger: none

# dynamically set the branch value, please change according to your real requirement
variables:
  ${{ if or( contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'release/test2'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'release/test3') ) }}:
      branch: $[ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
  ${{ else }}:
      branch: 'main'

pool:
  VMimage: Ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories: 
  - repository: repo-A
    name: 'wadetest1/test1'
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
    type: git
    trigger:
      - bugfix/*
      - release/*
      - dev1
  - repository: repo-B
    name: 'wadetest1/test2'
    type: git
    ref: $(branch)              #<- use the dynamic variable here
    trigger:
      - dev1
      - release/*
steps:
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: repo-A 
  - checkout: repo-B

It will checkout fallback branch main on repo-B, as it doesn't have release/test1 branch:

If commit on release/test2 or release/test3 branch which both repo-A, repo-B contain, it will trigger the pipeline as below:

Edit:
As per your new comment, you have about 25 repos, and repo-A could also use the fallback ref if the repo doesn't have the branch.
In DevOps, there is no simple fallback ref for repository resource.
In workaround i shared above, only used two repos, in this scenario, you can also change ref of repo-A to $(branch) so that it will dynamically use the branch.
However, since you have many repository resources, it could be hard to find the same branch between all repos, if you add multiple if expression to define the $(branch), it could be very complicated.
I understand your concern, i suggest you to raise a feature request in community link. More votes will raise the priority and engage product manager to take a look and consider to realize the feature. Thanks.

Hi, that was not exactly what I had in mind. I explained in my post that repo-a may have a release branch, but that repo-b may not have it. In your example, let's say the source branch is release/123. and it was triggered from repo-a. That may be a valid branch name, but if it doesn't exist for repo-b it will still fail.

@Rattletrap, the pipeline works on my side if repo-b doesn't have the release/test1 branch, you can check my attached screenshot. I used $(branch) for the repo-b ref to control the branch. I will also add another screenshot when it's triggered on release/test2 branch which both repo have this branch. To be more specific, i changed the if expression. Please change the if expression to meet your real requirement.

@Rattletrap, you can add all same branches from both repo in expression so that it can determine the repository ref for repo-b to checkout. Currently there is no simple fallback ref for repository resource. Please let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Hi, I still don't see how your solution works for me. Scenario 2 that I gave was just one example of many that I wanted to work. Another one could be that repo-b has a release/2024-1 and repo-a only has master. If a commit is made to repo-b in release/2024-1 then repo-a should use the master branch. So it would have to be dynamic and sort this out for each repo. And in reality we have about 25 repos.

I understand that there is no real fallback ref functionality, which I think we have to live with. Thanks!

@Rattletrap, thanks for your reply! I updated the reply with Edit part. You can raise a feature request for the fallback ref.

I don't think there is anything "built-in" in for such a scenario. You could probably try checking if the branch exists with a custom script using something like
git ls-remote -b --exit-code REPOURL $(Build.SourceBranch)
Then checking if the exit code ($?) is 0 (found) or 2 (not found). And based on that set a variable with SourceBranch or your fallback and use that in the ref: part.
But I'm unsure if this would actually work as you would need to check very closely when the pipeline resolves those things
